# Starling for IOS & Android: Very low FPS in a static situation

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, mobile, starling-framework

I created an application with Starling, on the new mobile devices it performs amazingly well, however on the older devices (e.g. iPhone 4) I encounter a very odd lag.

I have as far as I can tell a completely static situation:

There are quite a few display objects added to stage, many of them are buttons in case it matters, their properties are not changed at all after initialization (x, y, rotation, etc...).
There are no enterframes / timeouts / intervals / requests of any kind in the background.
I'm not allocating / deallocating any memory.

In this situation, there's an average of 10 FPS out of 30, which is very odd.

Since Starling is a well established framework, I imagine it's me who's doing something wrong / not understanding something / not aware of something.

Any idea what might be causing it?

Has anyone else experienced this sort of problem?

**Edit:**

After reading a little I've made great optimizations in every possible way according to this thread:
http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/performance_optimization

I reduced the draw calls from around 90 to 12, flattened sprites and set blendmode to none in specific cases to ease on CPU, and so on...

To my surprise when I tested again, the FPS was unaffected:

- fps: 6 / 60
- mem: 19
- drw: 12

Is it even possible to get normal fps with Starling on mobile? What am I missing?

I am using big textures that are scaled down to the size of the device, is it possible that such a thing affects the fps that much?

Comment: Testing FPS with "Release" mode correct? Are you using textures that are scaled down to match the resolution of the device before loading them? Are you mixing BLEND modes that are causing additional draw calls?, etc... reading and following the tips at http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/performance_optimization#always_make_a_release_build should help you out...

Comment: These tips are golden. Regarding "Load textures from files/URLs", I'm downloading different piles of assets for different situations, therefore I assumed compiling each pile into a SWF would be way faster than sending a separate request for each file. The problem is that as far as I know it can only be done using embed, which apparently uses twice the memory. Do you have any solution in mind to enjoy the best of both worlds?

Comment: I added an answer in order to reply to your last comment...

Comment: Please read the edit in my original question, it's far more important than the load textures issue. I'm testing in Release mode, using textures that are scaled down, and regarding blend modes - no.

Comment: If you are talking about an iPhone4 FPS, then yes, the texture sizes are a huge issue as the A4/SGX 535 gpu) can really struggle. But that said, I personally have not had any issues in getting 30/60 fps.

Comment: I have set my fps to 30. After more testing, I found out that I can add many textures (from the same TextureAtlas) and keep a steady 30/30 fps, but I noticed that textfields are the source of the lag. 12 textfields with very little text in each (somewhere between a few characters to 4 short words) result in a 10/30 fps. 1 draw call. I'm using BitmapFonts.

Comment: I've use a custom text render normally so I have not had 12 updating fields on screen at a time... but there are a number of things that can help with that, trying to remember them all.... If they are short in length, try flagging them as batchable and retest and watch your CPU usage as this method can impact that depending upon your textfield configurations, also depending upon update cycles,

Comment: recreating the textfields on each enterframe instead of updating the text can actually be faster (maybe that was only for truetype), also are you using the github master branch?,  and check the forum and github for any other clues on this one...

Comment: also depending on what/how you are using those textfields for, you can also use `normal` display textfields on top of Starling (aka the Display3d stage). I've done this several times depending upon the effect that I needed vs using Feathers or such....

Comment: I'm not on my normal dev box, but I do remember some old issues related to bitmap font perf, but they were all closed as far as I remember, again make sure that you are using the latest source from github and not some old SWCs

Comment: I'm using a quite up-to-date source. I did set batchable, hence 1 draw call for all of them combined. I'm not even updating the text, the situation is static as described in my original question. If by normal display textfields you mean those in the flash.display package, then I'm afraid it's not an option for me although it did cross my mind. I need to be able to put them in layers in between the rest of the children, and not just below everything and above everything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Starling is not a miracle solution for mobile device. There's quite a lot of code running in the background in order to make the GPU display anything. You the coder has to make sure the amount of draw call is kept to a minimum. The weaker the device and the less draw call you should force. It's not rare to see people using Starling and not pay any attention to their draw calls.

The size of graphics used is only relevant for the GPU upload time and not that much for the GPU display time. So of course all relevant texture need to be uploaded prior to displaying any scenes. You simply cannot try to upload any new texture while any given scene is playing. Even a small texture uploading will cause idling.

Displaying everything using Starling is not always a smart choice. In render mode the GPU gets a lot of power but the CPU still has some remaining. You can reduce the amount of GPU uploading and GPU charge by simply displaying static UI elements using the classic display list (which is where the Staling framework design is failing). Starling was originally made to make it very difficult to use both display system together that's one of the downsides of using this framework. Most professional I know including myself don't use Starling for that reason.

Your system must be flexible and you should embed your assets for mobile and not use any external swf as much as possible and be able to switch to another system for the web. If you expect to use one system of asset for mobile/desktop/web version of your app you are setting yourself up for failure. Embedding on mobile is critical for memory management as the AIR platform internally manages the cache of those embedded assets. Thx to that when creating new instances of those assets the memory consumption stays under control, if you don't embed then you are on your own.

Regarding overall performance a very weak Android device will probably never be able to go passed 10 fps when using Starling or any Stage3D framework because of the amount of code those framework need to run (draw calls) in the background. On weak device that amount of code is already enough to completely overload the CPU. On the other hand on weak device you can still get a good performance and user experience by using GPU mode instead of render mode (so no Stage3D) and displaying mostly raster graphic.

IN RESPONSE TO YOUR EDIT:

12 draw calls is very good (90 was pretty high).

That you still get low FPS on some device is not that surprising. Especially low end Android device will always have low FPS in render mode with Stage3D framework because of the amount of code that those framework have to run to render one frame. Now the size of the texture you are using should not affect the FPS that much (that's the point of Stage3D). It would help with the GPU uploading time if you reduce the size of those graphics.

Now optimization is the key and optimizing on low end device with low FPS is the best way to go since whatever you do will have great effect on better device as well. Start by running tests and only displaying static graphics with no or very little code on your part just to see how far the Stage3D framework can go on its own on those weak device without losing any FPS and then optimize from there. The amount of object displayed on screen + the amount of draw calls is what affects FPS with those Stage3D framework so keep a count of those and always seek ways to reduce it. On some low end device it's not practical to try to keep a 60fps so try to switch to 30 and adjust your rendering accordingly.

Comment: I understand it's the ideal way to load assets on mobile, however I have a games lobby, and I need to be able to load and unload different sets of assets on demand, so I can't possibly embed that many in one SWF, there can possibly be hundreds of games. It so happens that this logic would be useful to me on the web as well, so I ended up having one asset manager for everything. If you can solve this matter then perhaps I'll move to 2 different assets managers.

Comment: my answer is very informative, why would I get a down vote for that? Something tells me the person would never dare to explain why ...

Comment: hundreds of games? How would that work on Ios? You can't load external code in one Ios app so all those games have to be included right at the start anyway.

Comment: More like dozens of games, most of the code would be shared between games, mainly different assets. Bottom line it's possible and have already been done before, I'm not revealing any more specifics on purpose.

Comment: I really doubt out of all technology out there AIR is the only one that can magically hack into Apple code injection protection for Ios apps. Only code that is published with the app can run in that sandbox, period and that includes swfs published with any sort of code inside. As for assets you can do whatever that's not a secret.

Comment: That's what I meant, all the code is compiled in the main swf and the assets are loaded externally. With that said, what do you suggest?

Comment: What asset size are we talking about? 1G? More?

Comment: It'd probably take time for the overall size of all assets to reach that, but it's possible on the long run. Regardless, I'd like to avoid having all of it downloaded at once from the beginning, as a big download size would require Wi-Fi and take too much time, the initial download and installation must be very quick.

Comment: If I understood correctly the loading can't be improved in my specific case, however please read the edit my original question.

Comment: I have set my fps to 30 as you suggested. After more testing, I found out that I can add many textures (from the same TextureAtlas) and keep a steady 30/30 fps, but I noticed that textfields are the source of the lag.

12 textfields with very little text in each (somewhere between a few characters to 4 short words) result in a 10/30 fps. 1 draw call. I'm using BitmapFonts.

I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Comment: What TexField class are we talking about here? There's the classic one, the Staling one (never use that one) and then the Feather one.

Comment: Starling one - why never use it?

Comment: Cos that one was more an experiment than anything else, it's not optimized. You'll get a better result with Feather or the classic one.

Comment: By classic one do you mean flash.text.TextField? From posts I read from the developer of starling - starling textfields with bitmap fonts are extremely optimized and are the best choice in the starling framework.

Comment: This would go well beyond the scope of the question but to resume briefly, Starling was designed for beginners not for professionals. Because of that design choice, performance is lower than you would expect. Compare between different textfield types and you'll see.

Comment: I'll reward you the best answer, but before closing this topic would you please answer briefly - since feathers is based on the starling framework, it was designed for beginners as well wasn't it? So how come feathers textfield is better than starling's classic? (unless feathers is not a straightforward extension)

It's probably asking too much, but do you think it'd be possible to have a little chat about best performance practices for GPU on flash?
I could even open another question on Stackoverflow, if you'd like to be rewarded for the answer.

Comment: Feather is not an extension but it needs Starling to display its components. Feather has it's own ways of dealing with texts and do not use the Starling TextField as a base anywhere. Performance with GPU is such a vast subject that a chat or a post here would never be enough to cover it. Suffice to say Starling is not the most efficient solution but for many it's the only one. The alternative are: modifying Starling to perform better (I know a few companies that do that) or create you own engine (I know quite a few developers that have their own engine including myself)

Answer (score 0):

> Regarding "Load textures from files/URLs", I'm downloading different piles of assets for different situations, therefore I assumed compiling each pile into a SWF would be way faster than sending a separate request for each file. The problem is, for that I can only use embed, which apparently uses twice the memory. Do you have any solution in mind to enjoy the best of both worlds?

Instead of downloading 'over-the-wire' your assets and manually caching them for re-use, you can embed the assets into your app bundle vs. *embedding* them and then use the Starling AssetManager to load the textures at the resolution/scale that you need for the device:

ie.

```
        assets.enqueue(
            appDir.resolvePath("audio"),
            appDir.resolvePath(formatString("fonts/{0}x",    scaleFactor)),
            appDir.resolvePath(formatString("textures/{0}x", scaleFactor))
        );
```

Ref: https://github.com/Gamua/Starling-Framework/blob/master/samples/scaffold_mobile/src/Scaffold_Mobile.as

Your application bundle gets bigger of course, but you do not take the 2x ram hit of using 'embed'.

Misc perf ideas from my comment:

- Testing FPS with "Release" mode correct?
- Are you using textures that are scaled down to match the resolution of the device before loading them?
- Are you mixing BLEND modes that are causing additional draw calls?

Ref: The [Performance Optimization](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/performance_optimization) is great reading to optimize your usage of Starling.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, using assets.enqueue replaces the normal embed and would mean I'd have to embed all assets in 1 SWF, which would miss the point as I need to be able to load different SWFs with different assets in different situations, and not all at once.

Regardless - Is this solution also relevant for web applications or for mobile only? I'm building a cross platform application which should work on computer web browsers, ios and android.

Comment: About the ideas from your comment, I'm dong everything wrong at the moment and I understand how to fix it, except the point I mentioned.